# Android OpenCV - Converting OpenCV C++ Code to Android in order to detect QR Code Alignment Squares

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I am building an Android Application where I'm aiming to scan a form using OpenCV for Android. I am planning to use the same concept that QR Codes use, the alignment squares, in order to make sure that I'll make the scan properly every time.

I know I can just use the ZXing Library, however, I am not using a QR Code. I'm only borrowing the alignment square idea before I run my image processing on it.

I found [this blog](http://dsynflo.blogspot.com/2014/10/opencv-qr-code-detection-and-extraction.html) wherein he uses the OpenCV C++ Library to find the alignment squares and then he realigns the image and outputs a realigned QR Code. [His C++ Code can be found in his github here.](https://github.com/bharathp666/opencv_qr/blob/master/video.cpp) I don't have much background about C++ aside from the classes I took back in college and I haven't had experience in using OpenCV in C++. I understand most of the code is trying to do, however, as I was converting his functions outside the main function, I had an issue with this one:

```
void cv_getVertices(ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> contours, int c_id, float slope, ArrayList<Point> quad){
    Rect box = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(c_id)); //<-- problematic code
    //more code here
}
```

The original code is:

```
void cv_getVertices(vector<vector<Point> > contours, int c_id, float slope, vector<Point2f>& quad){
    Rect box;
    box = boundingRect( contours[c_id]);

    //more code here
}
```

However, I am getting an error because `Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(c_id));` is looking for a `MatOfPoint` Object, and my `contours` ArrayList is made up of points.

Note: I had to change a lot of his code like changing the `vectors` to `ArrayLists`, as well as rewriting when he's doing operations on `Points`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ variant of `boundingRect()` expects an `InputArray<T>` which has a constructor which accepts `const vector<T> &` therefor it implicitly  transforms the given `vector<T>` you pass into `boundingRect()` into `InputArray<T>`. This doesn't work with JAVA. You have to explicitly transfrom your ArrayList into `MatOfPoint` may be via `MatOfPoint.fromList(java.util.List<Point> lp)`

Comment: There's no `fromList` function in `MatOfPoint` or `MatOfPoint2f` object types.

Comment: @Razgriz I found it [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/MatOfPoint.html)

Comment: Nevermind that, I tried this `MatOfPoint mop = new MatOfPoint(); mop.fromList(contours.get(c_id)); Rect box = Imgproc.boundingRect(mop);` and it does not give errors any longer. Thanks for the lead.